# How to return the type of an anonymous for [ResponseType(typeof(...))]?

Tags: c#, .net, swashbuckle

I am working with a project .NET 6.0 Core API and Swashbuckle (Swagger) to generate doc and API on client's server.
Some of responses of apies are the anonymous such as `return Ok(new{true,Product))`. Product is the model.

Is there other solution to use `[ResponseType(typeof(...))]` for the anonymous type above except create a new response model for each of apis?

Or any suggestion for my project?

Comment: You could try return an ValueTuple instead of anonymous `return Ok( (true,Product) );`

Comment: Can you use `object` or `dynamic`?